# submit onclick better suggestion

Tags: ajax, onclick, submit

Below is my code in which i have a form from where user submits it but i need to update few data before submitting form and that will be taken from user.Right now i have not added input text before call link.

What could be the possible reason why its not submitting my form after ajax being called? Why cant i do this?? TIA

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showConfirm() {
        if(confirm('Are you sure?') == true){
            //$("#testform").submit();
            $("#showcall").show();
        return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function secondFunction() {
        $.ajax({
                 url: 'ajax_action.php',
                 success: function( data ) {
                    //alert(data);              
                    alert($("#testform").attr("method"));
                    $("#testform").submit();
                    //document.forms['myform'].submit();
                 }
            });         
        }
</script>   
<form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testform">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go" onclick="return showConfirm();" />
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="secondFunction();" id="showcall" style="display:none;">Call</a>
</form>
```

Here is my action.php

```
<?php
//echo 'working';
//echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Here is my ajax_action.php

```
<?php
    echo 'ajax called';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling the form from the id through jquery

```
$("#testform").submit();
```

add a name attribute to your form and then access it from the document object.

html:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testform" name="testform">
```

js:

```
document.testform.submit()
```

Comment: That showing me error in console as "document.testform.submit is not a function". And I have already tried for the same. Anyways thx mate.

Comment: did you add the name attribute to the form element? are you calling the same form name from document?

Comment: yeah mate i have added same name "testform" and yeah i have called it as document.testform.submit().